# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://my-resource.search.windows.net/indexes('my-index')?api-version=2017-11-11

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I need some help regarding the azure search(custom analyzers). I created index in azure search resource. I imported data from cosmosdb to my azure-search index. While adding the data to cosmos db I didn't add analyzers.Now I tried to update the index with analyzers and tokenizers through Rest API following below

```
 API(POST) https://my-resource.search.windows.net/indexes/my-index?api-version=2017-11-11
        {
            "name":"my-index",
            "fields":[

                { "name":"id", "type":"Edm.String", "key":true, "searchable":true,"filterable":true,"analyzer":"my_ngram" },
                { "name":"LastName","type":"Edm.String", "searchable":true,"filterable":true, "analyzer":"my_ngram" }
            ],
            "analyzers":[
                {
                "name":"my_ngram",
                "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
                "charFilters": ["html_strip"],
                "tokenizer":"my_tokenizer",
                "tokenFilters":[ "cjk_width","lowercase" ]
                }
            ],
            "tokenizers":[
                {
                "name":"my_tokenizer",
                "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenizer",
                "minGram":2,
                "maxGram":5
                }
            ]
        }
```

But I am getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://my-resource.search.windows.net/indexes('my-index')?api-version=2017-11-11'."
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to add custom analyzers for already created indexes for azure search?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try a GET request to that URL and see if you can get the index definition? Also, an [update operation to the index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-index) would be a PUT operation instead of a POST.

Moreover, adding custom analyzers to an existing index also requires **allowIndexDowntime** to be set to true.

```
https://[search service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]?api-version=[api-version]&allowIndexDowntime=true
```

You can find more information in the '[add custom analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers)' docs.

Comment: Good tip to try a GET at the PUT URL - GET worked for me but PUT still doesn't though :\ Any ideas?